# Removing a file from environment free using nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, file, path

I am making an application in the MERN stack and storing all my uploaded files within my local `backend api folder` under `app_name/src/uploads/`. For uploading I am using a node package `multer`.

Now, I made an API endpoint to remove a single file from the uploads folder too which works fine in the Windows environment, but for Mac, it is not working as expected due to the difference in paths in both environments.

This is the file path i am sending from front-end: `http:\localhost:8888\uploads\1689181645769-screencapture-2023-08-12-23_29_59.png`
Here is my API endpoint:

```js
const {
  file
} = req.body;
let stringiPath = "/uploads\\";
const filename = file.split(stringiPath);
const filePath = path.join(__dirname, '../..', 'uploads', filename[1]);
if (fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
  fs.unlink(filePath, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error deleting file:', err);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: 'Failed to delete file'
      });
    } else {
      console.log('File deleted:', filename);
      return res.status(HTTP_STATUS_CODE.DELETE_SUCCESS).json({
        status: HTTP_STATUS_CODE.DELETE_SUCCESS,
        message: MESSAGE.FILE_DELETED,
        success: true,
        data: null
      });
    }
  });
} else
  return res.status(HTTP_STATUS_CODE.NOT_FOUND).json({
    status: HTTP_STATUS_CODE.NOT_FOUND,
    message: MESSAGE.FILE_NOT_FOUND,
    success: false,
    data: null
  });
```

Can anyone assist me for a solution which will work for all operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

***Update***

I found the solution:

```js
const {
  file
} = req.body;
const fileName = path.basename(file);

const filePath = path.join(__dirname, '../..', 'uploads', fileName);
if (fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
  fs.unlink(filePath, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error deleting file:', err);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: 'Failed to delete file'
      });
    } else {
      console.log('File deleted:', file);
      return res
        .status(HTTP_STATUS_CODE.DELETE_SUCCESS)
        .json({
          status: HTTP_STATUS_CODE.DELETE_SUCCESS,
          message: MESSAGE.FILE_DELETED,
          success: true,
          data: null,
        });
    }
  });
} else {
  return res
    .status(HTTP_STATUS_CODE.NOT_FOUND)
    .json({
      status: HTTP_STATUS_CODE.NOT_FOUND,
      message: MESSAGE.FILE_NOT_FOUND,
      success: false,
      data: null,
    });
}
```

Fix:
Rather than just splitting path with hard code match which I was doing like this

```
let stringiPath = "/uploads\\";
const filename = file.split(stringiPath);
const filePath = path.join(__dirname, '../..', 'uploads', filename[1]);
```

I used the nodejs path to handle path according to the OS